# Crash debugging path investigation

Tags: qt, crash, crash-reports

My application crashes in a very unexpected way (every  hours) and I don't have any idea what's going on... I'm writting through a serial port in a `QThread`, but here the crash seems to come from the main thread:

```
Process:         Joker [244]
Path:            /Applications/Joker.app/Contents/MacOS/Joker
Identifier:      com.phonations.Joker
Version:         1.1.12
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [145]
Responsible:     Joker [244]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-08-26 18:13:43.772  0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  03B57F17-46F7-7ADF-1421-B431C3E2F5C5


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x600001c32900: Freeing already free'd pointer


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87148866 __pthread_kill   10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a33a35c pthread_kill   92
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff8a830b1a abort   125
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff89003bee nanozone_error   486
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff89002e2d nano_realloc   1121
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff89000c5d malloc_zone_realloc   79
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00007fff89001393 realloc   174
7   QtCore                          0x0000000107623cdf QByteArray::reallocData(unsigned     int, QFlags<QArrayData::AllocationOption>)   95
8   QtCore                          0x0000000107623662 QByteArray::resize(int)   274
9   QtSerialPort                    0x0000000107b7d7f5 0x107b73000   42997
10  QtSerialPort                    0x0000000107b7b93a 0x107b73000   35130
11  QtSerialPort                    0x0000000107b7dbee 0x107b73000   44014
12  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106bfef2c     QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)   300
13  QtWidgets                       0x0000000106c01a1d QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*)   6157
14  QtCore                          0x00000001078090b2 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject*, QEvent*)   114
15  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x00000001098f4bf4 0x109897000   383988
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff854a0107 __CFSocketPerformV0   855
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85460661 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__   17
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85451dd9 __CFRunLoopDoSources0   441
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8545149f __CFRunLoopRun   831
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85450f25 CFRunLoopRunSpecific   309
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8bc2ba0d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode   226
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8bc2b7b7 ReceiveNextEventCommon   479
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8bc2b5bc _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter   65
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e1c326e _DPSNextEvent   1434
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e1c28bb -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]   122
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8e1b69bc -[NSApplication run]   553
27  libqcocoa.dylib                 0x00000001098b0d44 0x109897000   105796
28  QtCore                          0x000000010780664d QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)   397
29  QtCore                          0x0000000107809652 QCoreApplication::exec()   354
30  com.phonations.Joker            0x000000010594e266 main   1958
31  com.phonations.Joker            0x0000000105912874 start   52

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff87149662 kevent64   10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86733421 _dispatch_mgr_invoke   239
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff86733136 _dispatch_mgr_thread   52

Thread 2:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff871489aa __select   10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8549dab3 __CFSocketManager   867
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a339899 _pthread_body   138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a33972a _pthread_start   137
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8a33dfc9 thread_start   13

Thread 3:: PhSonyController
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff853f2a25 CFHash   69
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff853eafd8 CFBasicHashFindBucket   1032
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff853eab9f CFDictionaryGetValue   111
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff85420a3a  [CFPrefsSource withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:perform:]   122
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8544a377 _CFPreferencesCopyValueWithContainer   231
5   QtCore                          0x00000001077b2e32 0x1075f6000   1822258
6   QtCore                          0x000000010778e0c7 QSettings::value(QString const
```

I'm using Qt 5.2.1 under MacOSX 10.9.3